# List of dictionaries remove semi-occurrences

Tags: python, list, dictionary, nested-loops

I have a **list** of **dicts**:

```
[{'name':'A', 'flag':'2','id':'x1'},
{'name':'A', 'flag':'2','id':'x2'},
{'name':'A','flag':'1','id':'x3'},
{'name':'B', 'flag':'2','id':'x4'}]
```

I want an output like :

```
[{'name':'A', 'flag':'2','id':'x1'},
{'name':'A', 'flag':'1','id':'x3'},
{'name':'B', 'flag':'2','id':'x4'}]
```

Remove duplicate dicts from list where : field **name** and **flag** are the same.
For example the second dict will be deleted because its a semi-duplicate with the first one same name, same flag (different ids but we dont care about ids: the idea is to delete al dict which have same **name** and same **flag** and keep only one of them
I can use nested loops but dont know if i can use list comprehension !?

Comment: Is your question whether comprehension can be used or not?

Comment: You want to remove duplicates on what keys? Each dict in your example input are distinct.

Answer (score 3):

One approach:

```
# create dictionary using as keys the values to remove duplicates 
lookup = {(d["name"], d["flag"]): d for d in data[::-1]}

# create list from the lookup values
res = [e for e in lookup.values()]

print(res)
```

**Output**

```
[{'name': 'B', 'flag': '2', 'id': 'x4'}, {'name': 'A', 'flag': '1', 'id': 'x3'}, {'name': 'A', 'flag': '2', 'id': 'x1'}]
```

If order of is important, just reverse the list:

```
print(res[::-1])
```

**Output**

```
[{'name': 'A', 'flag': '2', 'id': 'x1'}, {'name': 'A', 'flag': '1', 'id': 'x3'}, {'name': 'B', 'flag': '2', 'id': 'x4'}]
```

Using a dictionary to remove duplicates by key is a known Python trick.

Comment: This can be done in one line as well: `res = list({(d["name"], d["flag"]): d for d in data[::-1]}.values())`

Answer (score 2):

You can create `DataFrame` then remove `duplicated` and `keep first` from **name and flag** then back `df` to a list of dictionary like below:

```
>>> import pandas as pd
>>> lst = [{'name':'A', 'flag':'2','id':'x1'},{'name':'A', 'flag':'2','id':'x2'},{'name':'A','flag':'1','id':'x3'},{'name':'B', 'flag':'2','id':'x4'}]

>>> df = pd.DataFrame(lst)
>>> df
    name    flag    id
0      A       2    x1
1      A       2    x2
2      A       1    x3
3      B       2    x4

>>> df.drop_duplicates(subset=['name','flag'], keep='first').to_dict('records')
[{'name': 'A', 'flag': '2', 'id': 'x1'},
 {'name': 'A', 'flag': '1', 'id': 'x3'},
 {'name': 'B', 'flag': '2', 'id': 'x4'}]
```

Comment: Where is pandas in the question?

Comment: @DaniMesejo I only give an answer with the use of `pandas`, do OP say don't use `pandas`?

Comment: It is a solution.

Answer (score 0):

Using list comprehension:

```
my_list = [{'name':'A', 'flag':'2','id':'x1'},
{'name':'A', 'flag':'2','id':'x2'},
{'name':'A','flag':'1','id':'x3'},
{'name':'B', 'flag':'2','id':'x4'}]

new_list = []

[new_list.append(item) for item in my_list if {"name":item["name"], "flag":item["flag"]} not in [{"name":element["name"], "flag":element["flag"]} for element in new_list]]
```

---

```
new_list
>>> [{'name': 'A', 'flag': '2', 'id': 'x1'},
 {'name': 'A', 'flag': '1', 'id': 'x3'},
 {'name': 'B', 'flag': '2', 'id': 'x4'}]
```

Comment: Poor use of a comprehension to build another list using a list of Nones.

Answer (score 0):

To preserve order you can use a set to remember the keys you've seen and only add the keys you want to remember to the set:

```
data = [{'name':'A', 'flag':'2','id':'x1'}, {'name':'A', 'flag':'2','id':'x2'}, {'name':'A','flag':'1','id':'x3'}, {'name':'B', 'flag':'2','id':'x4'}]
seen = set(); seen_add = seen.add

res = [d for d in data if not ((x:=(d['name'], d['flag'])) in seen or see(x))]
```

---

```
[{'name': 'A', 'flag': '2', 'id': 'x1'},
 {'name': 'A', 'flag': '1', 'id': 'x3'},
 {'name': 'B', 'flag': '2', 'id': 'x4'}]
```